# flutter rive package, error: [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file

Tags: flutter, rive

i was trying rive for the first time in flutter. the following error came when i tried to pub get both rive: ^0.13.1 & rive: 0.11.11. but fortunately no error for, rive: ^0.8.4
the error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 (revision: 25.1.8937393)".
> Found existing prepared package.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 (revision: 25.1.8937393)" ready.
> Warning: An error occurred during installation: C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.temp\PackageOperation01\unzip.:
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Anup\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.temp\PackageOperation01\unzip
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:535)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:482)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3792)
> at com.android.io.CancellableFileIo.list(CancellableFileIo.java:171)
> at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doComplete(BasicInstaller.java:141)
> at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.complete(AbstractPackageOperation.java:197)
> at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:365)
> at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installSdkTool(DefaultSdkLoader.java:454)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.installNdk(SdkHandler.java:322)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NdkLocatorKt.findNdkPathImpl(NdkLocator.kt:231)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NdkLocatorKt.findNdkPathImpl(NdkLocator.kt:423)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.NdkLocator.findNdkPath(NdkLocator.kt:455)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getNdkStatus(NdkHandler.kt:85)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getNdkPlatform(NdkHandler.kt:98)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.gradle.generator.CxxConfigurationModelKt.tryCreateConfigurationParameters(CxxConfigurationModel.kt:211)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.CxxCreateGradleTasksKt.createCxxVariantBuildTask(CxxCreateGradleTasks.kt:84)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.doCreateTasksForVariant(LibraryTaskManager.java:216)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createTasksForVariant(TaskManager.kt:421)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createTasks(TaskManager.kt:325)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.kt:692)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2$1.call(BasePlugin.kt:575)
> at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:69)
> at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:54)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsResourceManager.recordBlockAtConfiguration(AnalyticsResourceManager.kt:207)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.AnalyticsConfiguratorService.recordBlock(AnalyticsConfiguratorService.kt:85)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2.accept(BasePlugin.kt:570)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2.accept(BasePlugin.kt:567)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:35)
> at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
> at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:171)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:168)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:95)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
> at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy42.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:247)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:244)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1434)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:253)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:114)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:761)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:152)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$1(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$9(StateTransitionController.java:196)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:192)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
> at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
> at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:49)
> at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
> at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
> at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
> at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
> at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:210)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:206)
> at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
> at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareToScheduleTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:71)
> at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$prepareToScheduleTasks$2(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:127)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransition$8(StateTransitionController.java:187)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransition(StateTransitionController.java:183)
> at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.prepareToScheduleTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:125)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:89)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:101)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:88)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
> at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
> at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 (revision: 25.1.8937393)" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 (revision: 25.1.8937393)" failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':rive_common'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.sdk.InstallFailedException: Failed to install the following SDK components:
> ndk;25.1.8937393 NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393
> Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `build.gradle` file that is inside the android folder of your project, this would be the path `android/app/build.gradle`. Inside that file, look for the part where the NKD version is and change it to the one it tells you in the log as I show you below:

```
android {
namespace "com.example.yourprojectname"
compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
...
}
```